# Need some help on rails trying to validate on ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

first of all this leading code does already works, the thing its that im trying to validate item quantity inventory left, and popup an alert and wont add the item to the cart, i been trying and trying but havent been able to handle that, thanks in advance.

So in CartController i have this:

```
class CartController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!
#validate :@product.ensure_product_quantity, on: :update

def update

begin

  @product = Product.find product_params[:id]
  #@product.ensure_product_quantity
  logger.debug "#{@product.ensure_product_quantity}"

  #if @product.ensure_product_quantity < 0
    #flash.now[:notice] = "Item added to cart"
    #session[:cart] << @product.item_for_cart(product_params[:quantity]).with_indifferent_access
    #session[:cart].delete_at(cart_item_params)
    #flash.now[:notice] = "True"
  #else
    #flash.now[:alert] = "No enough product left"
    #flash.now[:notice] = "False"
  #end

  #flash[:alert] = "Not enough product left" if @product.ensure_product_quantity > 0

  session[:cart] << @product.item_for_cart(product_params[:quantity]).with_indifferent_access
  flash.now[:notice] = "Item added to cart"
  #flash.now[:alert] = "No enough product left" if @product.item_for_cart(product_params[:quantity]) > @product.current_quantity

rescue => e

  if e.is_a? ActionController::ParameterMissing
    flash.now[:alert] = "Please make a selection to add this item"
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "Sorry, there was a problem adding this item"
  end

end
end
```

On Product model have ensure_product_quantity

```
  def ensure_product_quantity
      items.each do |item|
      errors.add(:base, "Not enough of '#{item.product.title}' left") if item.quantity > item.product.current_quantity
  end
      #logger.debug "llega"
  end
```

The above code works when you Select an desire item from menu, and you click on Add to cart button, what i want its to check if this product have enough product left, if not, dont add the item to the cart and show the user a message.

Comment: with all that code commented out it's hard to understand what you are actually doing there. rewrite your code and restructure your question so it's easy to understand what you have tried and what is not working exactly.

Comment: well thanks for answering, this line: `@product.ensure_product_quantity` , printed in console shows me a long collection, but never works to validate for example `if @product.ensure_product_quantity < 0` insted on the webpage shows the alert: `flash.now[:alert] = "Sorry, there was a problem adding this item"` so enters on the rescue block